# SQL Upgrade from 2008 to 2016. Varchar to Datetime Out Of Range

Tags: sql-server

I finally got our company to upgrade our oldest SQL Server which was 2008 to 2016, which is a god send.

However there are applications out there that use the SQL Database's for various things and a lot of applications error out when added dates into the SQL Table.

These obviously worked fine on SQL 2008, however on 2016 we seem to be getting conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value error.

Now I can rectify the situation by explicitly converting the date fields from VARCHAR by doing CONVERT(DATETIME,@DATE,103) however to have to go through every application and do this is a nightmare.

Is this the only solution I have? Or there something I've missed during the upgrade such as Language setup etc.

Cheers.

Comment: run `dbcc useroptions` on both looking for differences in the language/date format settings that will be displayed.

Comment: @AlexK.Checked - both match exactly.

Comment: I agree this definately sounds like the login's language setting has changed from what it was maybe British to English (a naming that's annoys the hell out of me, being English, as according to SQL Server I don't speak English... Should be English (UK) and English (US) or English and American). American's format their dates in the format `MM-dd-yyyy`, so if you're passing a `dd-MM-yyyy` date with the language set to "`English`" then it'll read it in the wrong format. With a date like today (`26-06-2017`) that would mean (to SQL Server) that you want to 6th day of the 26th month.

Comment: You could try, temporarily, changing the compatiblity of the database to 2008's (which is `100`). I would guess that it won't solve the issue though, as it's not the version that's the problem

Comment: It appears when I migrated the users, it set all their Language to English instead of British English. Figures. Thank You All for your assistance!